# Invalid JSON in the ‘operations’ multipart field in formData in next js application?

Tags: javascript, next.js, apollo-server, graphql-js

I have one mutation like this-

```
mutation signUp($avatar: Upload!) {
  signUp(
    avatar: $avatar
    input: { 
      name: "Siam Ahnaf"
      email: "siamahnaf198@aol.com"
      password: "12345678" }
  ) {
    message
    token
  }
}
```

For this I have sent a request from next js application like this-

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('operations', '{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!) {signUp(avatar: $file, input: {name: "Siam Ahnaf", email: "siamahnaf198@yahoo.com", password: "siam1980"}){message, token}}", "variables": { "file": null } }');
    formData.append('map', '{ "0": ["variables.file"] }');
    formData.append('0', Image);
    await axios({
        url: "http://localhost:3001/graphql",
        method: "post",
        data: formData,
        Headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Now I am getting error like - Invalid JSON in the ‘operations’ multipart field

But I can't understand where I am wrong in 'operation' json. Please help me.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Try console.logging `'{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!) {signUp(avatar: $file, input: {name: "Siam Ahnaf", email: "siamahnaf198@yahoo.com", password: "siam1980"}){message, token}}", "variables": { "file": null } }'` and make sure it's valid json. Maybe by parsing it with `JSON.parse`

Comment: The value you're passing to `operations` isn't a valid JSON string. Try escaping the double quotes inside the `query` value.

Comment: Can you describe more details

Comment: Replace the `operations` value with `'{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!) {signUp(avatar: $file, input: {name: \"Siam Ahnaf\", email: \"siamahnaf198@yahoo.com\", password: \"siam1980\"}){message, token}}", "variables": { "file": null } }'`.

Comment: @juliomalves it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm copying my answer here from [the almost-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619781/invalid-json-in-the-operations-multipart-field-please-see-this-question-here) in case that one gets closed:

If you have quotes inside quotes and you want to run `JSON.parse` on it, you have to escape them (as others have mentioned). However, in your follow-up duplicate, you can't just single escape the quotes. You have to double- or triple-escape them.

Here's the explanation:

```js
'{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!) {signUp(avatar: $file, input: {name: \"Siam Ahnaf\", email: \"siamahnaf198@yahoo.com\", password: \"siam1980\"}){message, token}}", "variables": { "file": null } }'
```

When this gets parsed by JavaScript (because it's inside single quotes), it takes the `\"` and realizes you're trying to escape them (unnecessarily, since it wasn't a single quote), so it converts it into `"`. Now the parser sees the value inside the quotes (escaped):

```js
{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!) {signUp(avatar: $file, input: {name: "Siam Ahnaf", email: "siamahnaf198@yahoo.com", password: "siam1980"}){message, token}}", "variables": { "file": null } }
```

As you can see, the syntax highlighter changes colors halfway through, because the quotes were already escaped.

To get the desired output, you have to make the FIRST string processing end up with backslashes in it, so you have to escape THE BACKSLASHES too:

```js
'{ "query": "mutation($file: Upload!) {signUp(avatar: $file, input: {name: \\"Siam Ahnaf\\", email: \\"siamahnaf198@yahoo.com\\", password: \\"siam198\\"}){message, token}}", "variables": { "file": null } }'
```

Now the question is if you need TWO backslashes or THREE. The answer here is that since your OUTER string uses single quotes, you don't need to ALSO escape the double quotes inside, so you only need two backslashes for every double quote you want to keep. If you were using double quotes for your outer string, you'd have to triple escape instead of just double, or your quote wouldn't also get escaped, and the original string would be invalid.

Rule of thumb: if you're trying to escape the SAME type of quote you're using for your string, triple escape. If you're trying to escape a different type, double escape.

Comment: Done! I am very happy that I am cried. I am in this problem for 20 days. Nobody can help me. You are very good person. For seeking the solution I ask almost 6 questions in stack overflow, 10 question dev.io, 8 issues in github. But nobody help me even the developer of graphql-upload and apollo server. Thank you very much. You are my boss now.